# Sum based on stolz theorem

Tags: real-analysis

The Sum is as follows:

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty}  \frac{1} {\sqrt n} \left( \frac {1} {\sqrt n}+ \frac {1} {\sqrt {n+1}} +...+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}  \right) $$.

I solved as follows using stolz theorem

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty}  \frac{x_n-x_{n-1}} {y_n-y_{n-1} } = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac {\frac {1} {\sqrt{2n}} - \frac {1} {\sqrt{2n-1}}} {\sqrt n - \sqrt{n-1}}$$

where $$ {\{x_n\} = \left( \frac {1} {\sqrt n}+ \frac {1} {\sqrt {n+1}} +...+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}  \right)}  $$
 and

$$ {\{y_n\} = \sqrt n}  $$

I rationalized the denominator and got the answer as zero.

But the solution in the book is given as

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty}  \frac{x_n-x_{n-1}} {y_n-y_{n-1} } = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac {\frac {1} {\sqrt{2n}} + \frac {1} {\sqrt{2n-1}}- \frac{1} {\sqrt{n-1}}} {\sqrt n - \sqrt{n-1}}$$

$$ = 2(\sqrt2-1) $$

how they got the second step that is 
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac {\frac {1} {\sqrt{2n}} + \frac {1} {\sqrt{2n-1}}- \frac{1} {\sqrt{n-1}}} {\sqrt n - \sqrt{n-1}}$$

Please explain. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: A reference that should have been given because this theorem is very ill-known :
 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem)

Comment: You can also solve it with Riemman's integral. This limit is $$\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x+1}}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made a mistake in evaluating $x_n-x_{n-1}$ \begin{align}x_{n}=&&\frac1{\sqrt n}+\cdots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n-2}}&+\frac1{\sqrt{2n-1}}+\frac1{\sqrt{2n}}\\x_{n-1}=&\frac1{\sqrt{n-1}}&+\frac1{\sqrt n}+\cdots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n-2}}\end{align}

They didn't.

Answer (score 0):

The second step follows from
$$
x_n - x_{n-1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n-1}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}},
$$
which you see by carefully noting which terms are present in $x_n$ which are not in $x_{n-1},$ and vice versa. When you go from $x_{n-1}$ to $x_n$ you gain two terms 'at the end', and loose one 'at the beginning.'